# Locally compact $T_2$ but not $T_4$ spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Does there exist an example of locally compact Hausdorff (each two points can be separated by disjoint neighborhoods) but not normal Hausdorff (each two *closed subsets* can be separated by disjoint neighborhoods) topological space?

Even if there is, does it carry the Tietz extension property (any continuous function to $\mathbb{R}$ on closed subset can be extended to the whole space i.e. the sheaf of continuous $\mathbb{R}$-functions is soft)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few of them: an easy way to find them: use [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=locally%20compact%20%2B%20T_2%20%2B%20%7ET_4) which incorporates the spaces from "Counterexamples in Topology" by Steen and Seebach.

The deleted Tychonoff plank $(\omega_1 + 1) \times (\omega + 1) \setminus \{\omega_1, \omega)\}$ is the classical example.

$\omega_1 \times [0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is another relatively easy example, if you know the relevant theory: It's locally compact and $T_2$ as a product of two such spaces. It's not normal, because it contains $P= \omega_1 \times (\omega_1+1)$ as a closed subspace (by Tikhonoff's embedding theorem, as the weight of $\omega_1 + 1$ is at most $\mathfrak{c}$, it can be embedded into $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ and compact subsets of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ are closed) and $P$ is not normal (classical; $X \times \beta(X)$ is normal iff $X$ is paracompact and $\beta\omega_1 = \omega_1 +1$, or use a pushing down lemma argument).

But a Mrówka $\Psi$-space based on a MAD family is also an example. See [this blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/) for proofs and definitions. This is not normal as it's pseudocompact and $T_3$ but not countably compact. Or use Jones' lemma.

I also like the rational sequence topology, it's not normal by a Jones' lemma argument. And it's the simplest to describe (no ordinals or MAD families).

The Tietze extension property for $X$ is equivalent to $X$ being normal. So these spaces don't obey it.

Comment: You could also quote the result that a space is hereditarily normal iff every open subspace is normal. So a locally compact normal space  X that is not hereditarily normal has a non-normal open subspace Y. And  Y is locally compact (because it is open in X, and X is both normal and locally compact).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't follow. You mean that any compact $T_2$ but not $T_5$ space contains an example as asked (which is true)?

Comment: If $X$ is normal and locally compact  but not $T_5$ then an open non-normal subspace $ Y$ is an example of a locally compact non-normal  Tychonoff ( and a fortiori) Hausdorff space.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet and all examples are of this form. It doesn't give us "new" or "concrete" examples.